# Creating a workbook then adding sheets from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, addition, spreadsheet

I need a VBA code that could create an excel file with a definite path,name and format , so i wrote these lines of codes :

```
Sub Parametrage()
'This is the workbook i need to copy sheets from , i chose to store those sheets in variable because i may need them later 
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Oumayna EL JAHRANI\Desktop\Test\Fichier Type.xlsx"
Dim ClasseurType As Workbook: Set ClasseurType = ActiveWorkbook
Dim Display As Worksheet: Set Publié = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Publié")
Dim Ajustements As Worksheet: Set Ajustement = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Ajustement")
Dim Variables As Worksheet: Set Variables = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Variables")
Dim Database As Worksheet: Set Source = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Source")
'Here starts the creation of the new file 
Dim CibleApp As New Excel.Application
Dim CibleClasseur As Workbook
Set CibleClasseur = CibleApp.Workbooks.Add
 With CibleClasseur
 .Title = "Classeur Cible"
 .Subject = "Cible"
 .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Oumayna EL JAHRANI\Desktop\Test\ObjetCible.xlsx"
 End With
'Here i add the sheets i want to my new workbook and this is the part i can't get to execute 
Sheets(Publié).Copy Before:=Workbooks(CibleClasseur).Sheets(1)
Sheets(Ajustement).Copy Before:=Workbooks(CibleClasseur).Sheets(2)
Sheets(Variables).Copy Before:=Workbooks(CibleClasseur).Sheets(3)
Sheets(Source).Copy Before:=Workbooks(CibleClasseur).Sheets(5)
Workbooks(ClasseurType).Close savechanges:=True
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

there are two problems in this code , first of all when i execute it it stops at line 16 , the second problem is that since it creates an xlsx file each time i execute for the second time i have an error at the line where i save the new file and i can't delete the old one afterwards . I want to first be able to execute the whole code and be able to delete the file and close the app if ever the code stops .

Comment: Why are you using separate instances of Excel? That is what is stopping you from copying the sheets.

Comment: I thought it was necessary to create a new file , Removing this part made deleting the new excel file easier , but it still doesn't permit copying the sheets

Comment: You're right but there's already a sheet in my file so i guessed that copy would add a new sheet and so that's why for the second one it was sheet(2) etc.. , is there any method to add a sheet ?

Comment: I didn't say anything about files. You are starting a completely separate instance of the **Excel application** and you can't copy sheets between different application instances. My question is why are you doing that?

Comment: Because i thought that if you do not have a new App you cannot create a newfile , which i knew was wrong thank's to you. So now that i know here's the new lines of code for that part
`Dim CibleClasseur As Workbook
Set CibleClasseur = Workbooks.Add
 With CibleClasseur
 .Title = "Classeur Cible"
 .Subject = "Cible"
 .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Oumayna EL JAHRANI\Desktop\Test\ObjetCible.xlsx"
 End With`

But my code is still not copying the sheets .

Comment: @Oumayma El Jahrani: At what line does your code stop and with what kind of error? Try, please, writing only the line in discussion. Otherwise, we cannot understand anything...

Comment: @Oumayma El Jahrani: Is `Sheets(Publié)` activated? If not, you must use `ClasseurType.Sheets(Publié).Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should look like this:

```
Sub Parametrage()
'This is the workbook i need to copy sheets from , i chose to store those sheets in variable because i may need them later

Dim ClasseurType As Workbook: Set ClasseurType = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Oumayna EL JAHRANI\Desktop\Test\Fichier Type.xlsx")
Dim Publié As Worksheet: Set Publié = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Publié")
Dim Ajustement As Worksheet: Set Ajustement = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Ajustement")
Dim Variables As Worksheet: Set Variables = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Variables")
Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ClasseurType.Worksheets("Source")
'Here starts the creation of the new file
Dim CibleClasseur As Workbook
Set CibleClasseur = Workbooks.Add
 With CibleClasseur
 .Title = "Classeur Cible"
 .Subject = "Cible"
 .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Oumayna EL JAHRANI\Desktop\Test\ObjetCible.xlsx"
 End With
'Here i add the sheets i want to my new workbook and this is the part i can't get to execute
Publié.Copy Before:=CibleClasseur.Sheets(1)
Ajustement.Copy Before:=CibleClasseur.Sheets(2)
Variables.Copy Before:=CibleClasseur.Sheets(3)
Source.Copy Before:=CibleClasseur.Sheets(5)
ClasseurType.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

It wasn't clear to me which workbook you intended to close at the end.